# Enforce type-checking when abstract method returns generic

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract

I have an abstract base class that calls a child class method.

```
abstract class Base<T> {
  protected abstract getProps(): T;

  public process() {
    const props = this.getProps();
    // process props...
  }
}
```

I want to enforce type-checking on the return type of a child method.

```
interface ChildProps {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}
```

The following code doesn't produce any errors

```
class Child extends Base<ChildProps>{
  protected getProps() {
    return {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: 'prop2',
      otherdata: 'foo', // <---- no errors
    }
  }
}
```

but when I set the return type explicitly, the code fails to compile (as expected)

```
class Child extends Base<ChildProps>{
  protected getProps(): ChildProps {
    return {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: 'prop2',
      otherdata: 'foo', // <---- gives an error "prop does not exist"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type checking in your example works fine. The object literal has all the properties of `ChildProps` and they are of the correct type. We can see an error if we break this contract.

```
class Child extends Base<ChildProps>{
  protected getProps() {
//          ^^^^^^^^  Type '() => { prop1: string; prop2: number; }' 
//                    is not assignable to type '() => ChildProps'
    return {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

You are expecting *excess property checks* to produce an error. But those are only done at a few places; mainly when an *object literal* is assigned to a variable with an *explicit type* or when an *object literal* is returned from a function with an *explicit type annotation*.

When a sub-class implements a method, *excess property checks* are intentionally disabled. After all, the sub-class to supposed to *extend* the super-class.

As you noted in your question, an explicit type annotation for `getProps` will enable excess property checks because an object literal is returned from a function with explicit return type.

```
class Child extends Base<ChildProps>{
  protected getProps(): ChildProps {
    return {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: 'prop2',
      otherdata: 'foo', // <---- gives an error "prop does not exist"
    }
  }
}
```

This will be your solution to avoid excess properties for now. Maybe the TypeScript Team will implement [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) at some point which may solve this issue.